# Foreach Array Element Search for values in multidimension Array javascript

Tags: javascript

Trying to match each element of an array to a set of coordinates in a multidimensions array in the following manner:

```
array1= [0, 5, 4]
array2 = [
{x: 1, y: 4, name: 'A', w: 0}, 
{x: 2, y: 8, name: 'E', w: 4}, 
{x: 3, y: 1, name: 'F', w: 5}];
```

I am hoping to match each element of array 1 to the value of w in array 2

```
0 -> {x: 1, y: 4, name: 'A', w: 0}
5 ->  {x: 3, y: 1, name: 'F', w: 5}
4 -> {x: 2, y: 8, name: 'E', w: 4}
```

I want to return :

```
[
{x:1, y,4}, {x:3, y:1},
{x:3, y:1}, {x:2, y:8},
...
];
```

Comment: try using `.filter()`

Comment: why `{x:3, y:1}` twice?

Comment: I want to draw edges to connect each node as in 
node1->node2
node2->node3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return the required x and y coordinates as an array.

Please find a working fiddle for that.

```js
const array1 = [0, 5, 4]
const array2 = [
  { x: 1, y: 4, name: 'A', w: 0 },
  { x: 2, y: 8, name: 'E', w: 4 },
  { x: 3, y: 1, name: 'F', w: 5 },
];
const tempArray = array1.map((item) => array2.find((node) => node.w === item));
// console.log(tempArray);
const finalArray = tempArray.map((currentNode, index, actualArray) => {
  const nextIndex = index === actualArray.length - 1 ? 0 : index + 1;
  return [
    { x: currentNode.x, y: currentNode.y }, 
    { x: actualArray[nextIndex].x, y: actualArray[nextIndex].y }, 
  ];
});
console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain array filter and map to do something like this

`Array.prototype.filter()` to filter all elements based on the index from first array and

`Array.prototype.map()` to modify the object so as to only show the x and y co-ordinates

```js
const array1 = [0, 5, 4];
const array2 = [
  { x: 1, y: 4, name: "A", index: 0 },
  { x: 2, y: 8, name: "E", index: 4 },
  { x: 3, y: 1, name: "F", index: 5 },
];

const newArr = array2.filter(x => array1.includes(x.index)).map(x => ({ x: x.x, y: x.y }));
console.log(newArr)
```